# undefined local variable or method `user' when visiting user profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a link to an image of the error I am receiving:

http://gyazo.com/fb646e7da96913eeb5acdf39adfc8865

Here is my UsersController:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here is the show view for User profiles:

```
<strong><%= user.username %></strong> <br>
<strong><%= user.name %></strong>



<div id="things" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @user.things.each do |thing| %>
    <div class='panel panel default'>
    <div class="box">
      <%= link_to image_tag(thing.image.url(:medium)), thing %>
      <div class='panel-body'>
      <strong><p><%= thing.title %></p></strong>
      <p><%= thing.description %></p>
      By <%= link_to thing.user.username, thing.user %>

      <% if thing.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to edit_thing_path(thing) do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to thing_path(thing), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> Delete
      <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Monk_Code's solution solved my problem. However, when I try to log in/sign up, I get "undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass" @Monk_Code http://gyazo.com/321f912c8466adab0bab216ef073842e. 

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

`<strong><%= @user.username %></strong>`
 
`<strong><%= @user.name %></strong>`

`@user` instead `user` 
read [Class and Instance Variables In Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)
and edit your html code

Comment: post your problem below questions

Comment: you are user `devise` gem? please tell me what application you're doing?

Comment: Yup. I am using the Devise gem. Do you actually want to visit the site? Would that be useful to you?

Comment: then you available helper `current_user` it is the user who is logged. Click on the link that I left in response, read the documentation `devise`

Comment: What does `current_user` have to do with the problem I'm facing?

Comment: I need more information about the application that would help you understand how

Comment: What exactly do you need from me? Do you want me to give you the link to the site?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42224/discussion-between-monk-code-and-dylan-richards)